# How to bring to front or order layers in Preview?

Tags: preview

I do a lot of selecting, copying, pasting, and moving around on a single image in Preview for Mac. But I'm having trouble ordering the layers of an image so that the layer I want visible is on top.

Is there any way to define layer order in Preview?

Comment: As far as I know you have to use something else to work with layers, like Gimp.

Answer (score 14):

If understand you right, here is how I change the order of layers in Preview app.

1. Select an object like an arrow or rectangle for example.
2. Right click on selected object.
3. Select an action from: "Bring Forward", "Bring to Front", "Send Backward", "Send to Back".

Comment: This doesn't exist anymore. Preview is getting worse and worse. See [user258934's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/301527/193261) below for updated advice.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to copy to the front by holding down "option" and dragging the image. Hope this helps.

Comment: Holding down "option" and then clicking to drag works fine on Yosemite. Thanks Tate!

Comment: In Mojave this seems to duplicate (copy & paste) the object rather than bring it forward.

Answer (score 9):

Since I don't have the option to move the object back or front (Mavericks) the only workaround I've found is to mark the objects you want to move to front, delete them and do the Undo - this will render them as newly put object, which sets them in front. That's a bit easier than recreating them in the right order.